# Where clause in expression and sum SSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

How can i create and expression to do the following:

SUM Aug-17 where Status = "Complete"

DIVIDE BY

SUM Aug-17 where Status = "UnitStarts"

I have tried the following:

```
(SUM(IFF(Fields!Status = "Complete",Fields!Aug_17)))/(SUM(IIF(Fields!Status 
= "UnitStarts",Fields!Aug_17)))
```

I am new to using Studio and can't seem to crack this one, as you can tell i should be coming back with a percentage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A few things you need to correct, I can't guarantee it will work after these changes as I can't test but it certainly won't work as it is so nothing to lose.

1: `IIF` requires three arguments

```
IIF(<Expression to evaluate>, <Result when True>, <Result when false>)
```

2: When you reference a field you have to explicitly state the property you want, this is usually the `Value` property.

So, your first IIF should read something like

```
IFF(Fields!Status.Value = "Complete",Fields!Aug_17,0)
```

3. Expressions usually start with an equals sign.
4. (optionally) you don't need the extra parentheses around each `SUM`

So the final expression should look something like this.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Status.Value = "Complete", Fields!Aug_17.Value, 0))
 / 
 SUM(IIF(Fields!Status.Value = "UnitStarts", Fields!Aug_17.Value, 0))
```